# Outlook iOS App showing icons for sender and even buttons. How?

Tags: outlook

[image: Outlook iOS screen shot]

Outlook iOS is showing avatar photos from external commercial senders in its list as shown by the attached screen shot. For Amazon it goes a step further and shows a button to track shipments in the shot as well.

I’m trying to figure out how to embed our enterprise logo into emails to achieve the same effect. An email with our logo and perhaps a “click or touch to respond to this support issue” button would help us to stand out. There is no doc I could find online.

Anyone have an idea of how or where to look?

Comment: Outlook email is also showing icons for Bank of America, Google and Paypal.  I want this for my website !!!  :-)

Comment: Still waiting for someone who has done it to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it!  BIMI is what causes this logo to work! Here are the links:

BIMI

https://mailchimp.com/marketing-glossary/bimi/

Check your domain for BIMI

https://bimigroup.org/bimi-generator/

Thanks!
John.

Comment: Funny. I also found this yesterday. Will give it a go. Did you try it already?

Comment: I am researching.  One thing I have found is that some email providers (e.g., GMail) will reject BIMI unless there is a VMC certificate, which costs at least US$999 per year plus your trademark has to be registered.  There is a self-asserted option but I think that most email providers are going to accept that.  You also have to have DMARC and SPF fully set up.

Comment: Yeah i heard similar, hopefully they'll drop the crazy trademark requirement.  It will limit BIMI to just the elite which is not gonna help the overall adoption or security of using it.  Imagine a trademark requirement for a favicon.

Comment: Ooh I found this at Google.... Quote.... "Note: Today, the BIMI standard requires your logo to be a registered trademark to get a VMC. However, the standard is being expanded to include logos that aren’t trademarked."  .... Now we just need letsencrypt to do vmc for free.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can display your logo within Outlook by creating and customizing a Bing Pages profile.

Bing Pages lets users manage their own brand on Microsoft products, such as Outlook. It's free and only requires a Twitter account, plus an Instagram, Facebook, YouTube, Pinterest, Twitch, or TickTock account with 100+ followers that’s made at least one post within the past 30 days.

The Gmail requirement for a Verified Mark Certificate (VMC) can be avoided with these steps:

1. Create a [Google account](https://accounts.google.com/signup) with your company's email address.
2. Change the profile picture to your company's logo.
3. Wait up to 48 hours for the logo to become visible in the inbox.

Do not create the Google account using the "To manage my business" option. This account type isn't able to change its profile picture, and the account type can't be changed after its created.

**For everyone else:** 
First, you will need complete the BIMI specification. Then, you will need to complete any additional requirements that each email service provider may have to display the logo in their inbox. This [tutorial](https://medium.com/p/77d713cb9e45) walks you through the process and explains everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for this; I am trying both right now.